# Get Access Token for Azure DevOps PAT

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I build an electron app, where I use git in the background. I would like to use Azure DevOps git repositories and would like to authenticate with PATs. So, I set up an enterprise application with these permissions:

[image]

In the app, I use the azure @azure/msal-node library to retrieve an access token. For scopes I am using

`scopes: ["https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation"]`

The token looks fine and has the following entry:

```
...
"scp": "user_impersonation",
...
```

I want to call this api to get started:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP, but I receive a 203 status response with this respone (in form of a responseUrl):

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The requested operation is not allowed.",
"typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.InvalidAccessException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"InvalidAccessException",
"errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Any input on where I am doing something wrong is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` as below:

[image]

Now, I generated one **access token** via Postman giving same scope with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation
code: <code>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got the **203 error** when I used the above bearer token in calling this query to list PATs:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/sridevops14/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, change your scope to
> `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` while generating
> access token.

To get `authorization_code`, you need to run the request below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran above request in browser, I got code successfully in address bar like this:

[image]

When I included this code in below request, I got token successfully like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token in below query, I got list of **PAT tokens** successfully like below:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/sridevops14/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to change **scope** to  `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` while generating access token like this:

```
scopes: ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I changed the scope, but still receive the same 203 response. When using the same token to retrieve the user information of the logged in user, the token works properly. (code is used from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop)

I would like to test the calls directly with postman as presented in your solution, but I fail to retrieve the authorization_code. I am wondering if there is a misunderstanding - I use user tokens, not a functional user with a client secret.

Comment: The link you mentioned in the comment is for calling Microsoft Graph API so you can fetch user information but it won't work for Azure DevOps API. I updated the answer by including the request to get code. You can check it!